# Python version changed After installing Spacy Module from 3.x to 2.7

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spacy

I have installed anaconda and my default version of python is 3.7.0 then i have create new virtual named pd then i installed spacy package of python as
***conda install -c conda-forge spacy*** 
then i have checked my python version it is showing 2.7.14.
My projects requirement for python version is is 3.x.
And also my default python version outside pd environment is 3.7.0.

Can someone help me to solve this problem......

My project requirement is Python3 and also Spacy package

Comment: You must have created a python 2 environnent on your own. The Python version can't change once you create the environment.

Comment: I have the same issue as well.  
conda create -n spacy python=3.4
conda activate spacy
conda install -c conda-forge spacy

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

    python:          3.4.5-0                                  --> 2.7.15-h2880e7c_1006 conda-forge
    vc:              10-0                                     --> 9-0                  conda-forge

Answer (score 1):

Can you just create a new environment for your project?

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6
conda install spacy
```

When you want to use this environment just type:

```
source activate py36
```

or if you are on windows :

```
activate py36
```

Check the documentation [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this command:

```
python3 --version
```

What was printed?

Comment: Version of python3 will definitely print 3.6, but the discussion is regarding the version of python. The solution suggested below works well.